# How to pass data value in php from jQuery’s $.ajax() function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on **jQuery code** as shown below in which I am  trying to pass **data value in php** from **jQuery’s $.ajax() function**.

> HTML Code:

```
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="width:90px;" type="submit"  name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>"  class=" go-btn btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button></td>
```

> jQuery Code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {
            $('.go-btn').click(function()
            {
                let target = $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    spanEl = $('.file-name[data-id='+ target +']');

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://abc.xyz/status.php',      // http://abc.xyz/status.php is the place where all my html/php/js code is sitting. 
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id: target}, //change to what you want
                    success: function(res)
                    {           
                        //alert(res)
                    },
                    error: function(res)
                    {
                        alert('Hello World!')
                    }
                })
            })
        });
```

> Php code:

```
<?php 
     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") and !empty( $_POST['go-button'] ) )
    {       
     $value = $_POST['id'];
     print_r($value);        // Line #A   // it doesn't print any value. 
     foreach ($mp4_files as $f)  // Line#B
     { 
            // conversion of mp4 into mp3 is happening.
     }
    }
?>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I have passed `$value=$_POST['id'];` in the php code above but on debug `print_r($value);` it doesn't print any value.

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php so that I am able to pass data value from AJAX function in php.

Comment: you HTML code is invalid. Is this a `<td>` or a `<button>` or a button inside a td?

Comment: i think not necesary your submit atribute on td, and are you sure that php is set value to your atribute data ?

Comment: remove submit an set button and try it again

Comment: Check `$_POST` array to see that there is no `id` or `go-button`

Comment: @AlexKudryashev how can I see `$_POST` array ?

Comment: _how can I see $_POST array_ - in your PHP file, before the `if` statement: `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: I am getting this `Array ( [go-button] => Go )`

Comment: @flash Your form is be posted via HTML not AJAX then. jQuery is only submitting `id`, `go-button` comes from HTML. Try `return false` from jQuery or add the `ev` arg and `ev.preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with ajax but with jquery. You're trying to get data-id from class .go-btn, but if you have more than one button with the same class JS wont detect which button you pressed.

A solution would be to set the class on your table and let jquery detect all the buttons inside the table, like this:

```
<table class="go-table">
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;">
    <button style="width:90px;" type="submit"  name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>"  class=" go-btn btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button>
</td>   <td style="width:5%; text-align:center;">
    <button style="width:90px;" type="submit"  name="go-button" value="Go" data-id="<?php echo $key; ?>"  class=" go-btn btn btn-outline-primary">Go</button>
</td>
```

And for your jquery change it to this:

```
$('.go-table').on('click', '.go-btn', function()
        {
            let target = $(this).attr('data-id'),
                spanEl = $('.file-name[data-id='+ target +']');
```

And it should get the data-id attribute. On the side note if you're using ajax you don't need type submit on your buttons.